# Extração de valor de objeto datetime em Python.

Tags: python, datetime

Tenho como necessidade extrair somente a hora de um objeto datetime.
Como proceder?
O objeto retorna a seguinte saida: "3 days, 22:01:00"

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você precisa utilizar o seguinte módulo da seguinte biblioteca:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

depois é só fazer:

```
 now = datetime.now()

 print("%s:%s:%s" %(now.hour,now.minute,now.second))
```

output:

```
23:4:58
```

Se quiser somente a hora, é só utilzar o `now.hour` e printar ele.

seria isto que você queria?

Answer (score 2):

Usando o método `strftime()` com a formatação `%H` e retornando `string`:

```
from datetime import datetime
obj = datetime.now()
hora = datetime.strftime( obj, "%H")
print(hora)
```

Usando o atributo `hour` do objeto `datetime` e retornando um `int`:

```
from datetime import datetime
obj = datetime.now()
print(obj.hour)
```